# Refresh the back page when the device back button is clicked in flutter in go router package

Tags: flutter, dart, gorouter

I have two pages and I want to refresh the previous page when the device back button is pressed, it is possible to do that in default navigation with async-await, but I can not do it with the go router package, can anyone suggest smth with GO ROUTER PACKAGE in flutter?

Comment: Hello there,
I believe this can be achieved by using statenotifier/changenotifier/valuenotifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wait until the screen is close by writing

```
await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourScreen()));
doRefresh();
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it with default navigation, my question is how to do it with go router navigation with go router package? It doesn't return a future that's why I didn't find a solution in go router package

Comment: Hi @NijatNamazzade, I was wondering if you've found some solution to this?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue

Comment: according to the documentation of `go_router` package, you can wait for result when you use the function `push`, reference: https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html